# Problelm with webcam in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, visual-c++-2010-express

I'm trying to write a code for detecting an object in OpenCV. But I don't know what the problem is with my laptop webcam that I just get a gray window. I mean the webcam LED in on but the window is gray and showing nothing. I searched the site and I know there were people with the same problem and it has been explained before but none of the solutions worked for me. Anyway here's my code I would be glad if you could help me! Thanks.

By the way I'm using Windows 8.1, OpenCV 2.2 and Visual c++ 2010 Express. If there may be any incompatibility in regards to windows or anything let me know.

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include<iostream>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture capWebcam(0);

    if (capWebcam.isOpened() == false) {
        std::cout << "error: capWebcam not accessed successfully\n\n";
        return(1);
    }

    cv::Mat matOriginal;
    cv::Mat matProcessed;

    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> vecCircles;
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f>::iterator itrCircles;

    cv::namedWindow("Original");
    cv::namedWindow("Processed");

    char charCheckForEscKey = 0;

    while (charCheckForEscKey != 27) {
        if (capWebcam.read(matOriginal) == NULL) {
            std::cout << "error: frame not read from webcam\n\n";
            break;
        }

        cv::inRange(matOriginal,
            cv::Scalar(0, 0, 175),
            cv::Scalar(100, 100, 256),
            matProcessed);

        cv::GaussianBlur(matProcessed,
            matProcessed,
            cv::Size(9, 9),
            1.5);

        cv::HoughCircles(matProcessed,
            vecCircles,
            CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
            2,
            matProcessed.rows / 4,
            100,
            50,
            10,
            400);

        for (itrCircles = vecCircles.begin(); itrCircles != vecCircles.end(); itrCircles++) {

            std::cout << "ball position x=" << (*itrCircles)[0]
                << ", y=" << (*itrCircles)[1]
                << ", z=" << (*itrCircles)[2] << "\n";

            cv::circle(matOriginal,
                cv::Point((int)(*itrCircles)[0], (int)(*itrCircles)[1]),
                3,
                cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0),
                CV_FILLED);

            cv::circle(matOriginal,
                cv::Point((int)(*itrCircles)[0], (int)(*itrCircles)[1]),
                (int)(*itrCircles)[2],
                cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0),
                3);
        }

        cv::imshow("Original", matOriginal);
        cv::imshow("Processed", matProcessed);

        charCheckForEscKey = cv::waitKey(10);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Is this question about C++ or C? choose one tag!

Comment: @Miki At first glance, it looks like this code is both valid C++ and valid C. And the answer will probably also be valid in both C++ and C.

Comment: @immibis I'm asking because the code is using old (obsolete) C OpenCV api. It makes a lot of difference answering for C or C++ api.

Comment: Actually I have another code for C++ too that has the same problem so I thought put both tags. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: @MohammadJavad then discard this code (C syntax is obsolete, as well as OpenCV 2.2, actually :D ), and work only on C++ api. Please post the code with the C++ api then.

Comment: can't you help me with this one ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I started learning OpenCV with this api, but was years ago. I don't remember :D

Comment: http://codepad.org/2KjUfQo0

Comment: this is again opencv 2.2

Comment: Please update your question with including C++ code snippet you provided in comments.

Comment: @MohammadJavad I tested on OpenCV 2.4.9 and OpenCV 3.0 (on Visual Studio 2013) and works ok. I can only recommend you to update OpenCV to a newer version. Good luck!

Comment: one quick question, I had windows 7 on my laptop before and it was already  installed on it I changed it to win8.1 and I thought this problem is maybe because of the webcam driver, don't you think??

Comment: Seyyed, it could be that but you'd better give it a try. Reinstall it.

Comment: Can you check if the webcam works correctly with another program?

Comment: yes it works properly! I checked.